# conversion from NSData to NSImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I am working in a project where i am fetching the result from server, it is coming like data form means as digit & alphabets so i want to change that blob value to image view please help me it is too difficult to me.

Comment: A bit more information would help. What kind of data are we talking about?

Answer (score 11):

You can make a `NSImage` object with NSData  as -

```
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

this will work if whatever data you are passing in it should be data of a image.

Comment: NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data]

Comment: so plaese tell me for objective c i have nsdata & i want to convert it in NSImage not in UIImage please help me

Comment: this is my whole code at first line i am saving the output of a fetching result from fire by the transaction.